# Sass/Compass Warning/Error with "gem install modular-scale"

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

Recently I tried adding `gem install modular-scale` via `command line`

Here's the error I got, can anyone help me out - i am relatively new to the command line, so speak slowly! :)

```
localhost:~ brock$ gem install modular-scale

WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
      /usr/bin aren't both writable.
ERROR:  Error installing modular-scale:
    modular-scale requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
 localhost:~ brock$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: I recommend organizing everything using RVM.  You also avoid lots of common permission issues installing gems the old fashioned way.

Since it's complaining about the RubyGems version you have, you should check what you actually have by entering this:

`$  gem environment`

Look for "RUBYGEMS VERSION" at the top.  If this is older than 1.3.6, modular-scale will need it to update.

```
$  gem install rubygems-update
$  update_rubygems
$  gem update --system
```

If you want to start working with rvm, go the https://rvm.io/.

Whichever way you go, you probably need to update RubyGems to allow installing modular-scale.

EDIT: You have RubyGems 2.2.2, but obviously, it doesn't see it.  You could run the gem install with sudo, but I don't recommend that.  The best way is to use RVM.  Install and add ruby 1.8.7 (assuming that's what you need)...

```
$  \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7
```

Read the [basics of RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/basics#the-basics-of-rvm), it'll make your life easier with managing different gems and rubies.

I also recommend adding .ruby-version  and .ruby-gemset files to your root directory of your app.  like:  /var/www/my-app/   In there, add two files like this:

```
$  ECHO "1.8.7" > .ruby-version
$  ECHO "my-app" > .ruby-gemset
```

Then leave the folder and come back in the terminal.  It will ask you to accept using these, answer yes.
Then, whenever you `gem install whatever` it will stay in this gemset and not mess with gems installed on any other apps you have.  This is why you don't want to `sudo gem install some-gem` because that will install the gem and its version globally.  Each time you come back to this folder, it will instantly pick up the right ruby version and gems.

Comment: The updates worked it was 1.3.5 and now it's 2.2.2, so that's a big step up. Genius.

`localhost:~ brock$ gem environment`

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8


I do have RVM installed but don't really know what I'm doing with it.

Comment: So now, I seem to have some sort of conflict?
'localhost:~ brock$ gem install modular-scale'
'Successfully installed modular-scale-2.0.4'
'Installing ri documentation for modular-scale-2.0.4'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block'
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block'
I guess this is precisely why RVM was created right?

Comment: Pretty much.  I edited my solution above because comments don't allow nice formatting like I needed to show.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Done a `rvm install 1.8.7` but it gives me this error. `'Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.`
`No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-1.8.7-p374.`
`It is not possible to build movable binaries for rubies 1.8-1.9.2, but you can do it for your system only.`
`Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.`
`Checking requirements for osx.`
`Installing requirements for osx.`
`Updating system........................`
`Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.8.7-p374'`